# Dictionary from variables that may not be initialized

Tags: python

I want to create dictionary, while I don't know if some variables used as values in this dictionary are initialized.

I can make simplified example:

```
x = 1
y = 3
z = None
```

So I have three variables to take in consideration, but I don't know if all are initialized (in this case only x and y are initialized) and I want to create dictionary, which in this case should look like:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 3}
```

I suspect there is nice Python snippet that can make this dictionary elegantly, unlike my current code, which I don't even want to show.

Comment: `z` is initialised as well. It just has `None` as the value. Do show your code; it'll perhaps make your intent clearer.

Comment: Python doesn't have uninitialized variables; it has names that either exist (and refer to an object) or don't exist.

Comment: You are right, I thought I will get NameError and for that reason I complicated my code. Sorry for lack of inteligence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little hazy on what you actually want here, but maybe something like:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if v is not None and not k.startswith('__')}
```

Example:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 3
>>> z = None
>>> d = {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if v is not None and not k.startswith('__')}
>>> d
{'y': 3, 'x': 1}
```

Comment: This dict comprehension is what I'll use. Thanks